# system/system2 command in R

Tags: r, shell, system, administrator

I'm using system command in R for invoking an OS command. The problem is that my OS command works only when I use it as administrator from the shell. How I can work from R as administrator?
Using simply `system(command)` access to files is denied. How I can solve? Thank you!!

Comment: You should reconsider doing this. A bug in your R code can seriously mess up your system if you give it admin rights. Also, what's your OS?

Comment: my OS is windows. Its's not a problem because is not something difficult but it needs admin rights

Comment: maybe it's because the programm that I'd like to run from R is stored in :C (no way, this program for work must be there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved just clicking on R icon and runned it as adminstrator!